# how do I integrate powershell into C sharp

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powershell, imgur

I've got all the scripts done, and I wrote out the entire C# GUI in Visual Studio Enterprise 2015.

I just need to get the button to launch a specific script when its clicked (Control.OnClick Method?).

I tried finding examples, but they were incredibly vague.

[image]

The hopeful outcome is as follows:

```
###   Begin Code   ###

##   C# psuedo code here   ##

//make C# bunifu Button 1 call script on click of button1

Invoke.OnClick Method (Or Correct option)

//Functional Example of an Invoke.OnClick Method Here doing something here. This is so I can learn and understand.

Place holder

//powershell equivalent
$SOCMonkeyDoStuff = Invoke-Item "C:\Powershell\Scripts\BecomeOneWithCodeMonkeys\Script.ps1


//Button Interaction in Powershell

$Title = "Task Menu"
$Caption = @"
1 - Get Running Services
2 - Get Top Processes
3 - Get Disk Utilization
Q - Quit

Select a choice:
"@

$coll = @()


$a = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription]::new("&1 Services")
$a.HelpMessage = "Get Running Services"
$a | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name Invoke -Value {Get-service |     where {$_.status -eq "running"}} -force

$coll+=$a
```

And I know, yes this code already works, why not just do it in powershell? The reason is is I plan on turning it into a platform agnostic tool in the very near future so Linux and Windows can both use it, and Id like to remain as vendor neutral as possible. Additionally, I plan on exporting it as a .exe so that it can be installed anywhere.

Comment: You can call scripts with "Process.Start("full path here")... as a quick hack

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c/

Comment: @BugFinder Ok, so my breakdown is this. I touched Visual Studio for the first time...about 14 hours ago. 

First time Ive ever done a UI that actually looks nice was when I installed VS Ent. 2015. I have no idea where to put the process.start code, although I do believe the correct code would be:'code'

    process.start(""C:\Powershell\Scripts\BecomeOneWithCodeMonkeys\Script.ps1")   'code'

Is that correct?

Comment: You'd want an @ in front of that parameter or to do double \\ either is your choice.  You put the Process.Start in your button click .. :)

Comment: @Mhd 

I actually found that article, and it was an incredible one, so thank you for sharing that. I do apologize for not including all my sources ive used so far.

I was able to follow the instructions and import all the references required, as well as locate the system.management.automation.dll file as well.

My issue, is with this code, I have no idea where or how to put it to make it work.

I understand namespace declares the instance, and program defines the class, but how do I put that into the bunifuflatbutton1, or do I? I have no idea. LOL

Comment: @BugFinder Ok, so lemme see if Im tracking: 'code'

//Make BunifuFlatButton1 execute script

\\process.start(""C:\Powershell\Scripts\BecomeOneWithCodeMonke‌​ys\Script.ps1") 

And I just put that into the button code somewhere?

 // bunifuFlatButton1
            // 
            this.bunifuFlatButton1.Activecolor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(0)))), ((int)(((byte)(102)))), ((int)(((byte)(204)))));
            this.bunifuFlatButton1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(26)))), ((int)(((byte)(32)))), ((int)(((byte)(40)))));

...

'code'

Comment: OK @Fallenour from the form designer, double click the button - paste the code in there.

Comment: @BugFinder I got build errors :(

Code Entered: 'code'

  \\ "Process.Start(""C:\Powershell\Scripts\BecomeOneWithCodeMon‌​ke‌​ys\Script.ps1")

'code'

Answer (score 3):

You could create a function that takes the path to a PowerShell script as its argument, and then execute said script. Could be as simple as:

```
private void RunPSScript(string path)
{
    using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        // add the script to the PowerShell instance
        ps.AddScript(path);

        // run it
        ps.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Then all you need is an event handler for the `OnClick` event of the button to invoke the function. I've never worked with the Bunifu library, so I don't know if `OnClick` is the right event name, but this is how it would look with Forms or WPF:

```
bunifuFlatButton1.OnClick += bunifuFlatButton_OnClick;
```

With the event handler looking something like:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string scriptPath;
    // assign value to scriptPath here

    // then invoke the method from before
    RunPSScript(scriptPath);
}
```

Remember to add a reference to the `System.Management.Automation` assembly in your project (basically the PowerShell API)

Comment: Im not sure I understood this. PLease see code below:



private void RunPSSCript(stringpath)
{
    using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        ps.AddScript(path);

        ps.invoke();
    }
}

namespace VenatorUI
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        
        private void bunifuFlatButton1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string scriptPath("C:\Script\Powershellscript.ps1");
            RunPSScript(scriptPath);
        }
    }
}